# org-mode not showing entries with timestamp

Tags: org-mode, time-date

I have the following entry in an org-mode file running emacs 26.3 freshly installed:

```
** lorem ipsum
   <2021-05-09 Sun>
```

When opening the agenda or clicking  the date there will be no entry in the calendar.
Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to be found here:

https://orgmode.org/worg/org-configs/org-customization-guide.html

"Just open a .org file, press `C-c [` to tell org that this is a file you want to use in your agenda, and start putting your life into plain text. "